# Download by clicking href link

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, href

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
#from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager


Base_Link="https://www.nseindia.com/market-data/bonds-traded-in-capital-market"

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
options.add_experimental_option('excludeSwitches', ['enable-logging'])

s = Service('C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chromedriver.exe')
driver1 = webdriver.Chrome(service=s, options=options)

#Set default zoom to 80%
driver1.get('chrome://settings/')
driver1.execute_script('chrome.settingsPrivate.setDefaultZoom(0.8);')

driver1.get(Base_Link)
driver1.maximize_window()
time.sleep(2)

e1=driver1.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT,"Download (.csv)")
driver1.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", e1)


time.sleep(10)
```

On the site, there is a link Download csv. Once we click it charts are downloaded automatically. I am trying to simulate click () but it is not working. I might be selecting the wrong id or maybe I using the wrong interaction with the element.

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Change the below line:

```
e1=driver1.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT,"Download (.csv)")
```

To:

```
e1=driver1.find_element(By.ID,"dwldcsv")
```

**Root cause of your issue:** Below is the HTML which you are trying to locate and `click()`, this is not an anchor tag(which means there is no `href` attribute). Hence you cannot use locator `By.LINK_TEXT`

```
<span id="dwldcsv">Download (.csv)</span>
```

**Solution:** Just use the value from `id` attribute as it is going to be unique and can easily locate the element.

Comment: I tried this solution it does not do anything. Can you see if it works on your machine. May be some problem in my installation.